# SSRS Remote Data Source fail to login

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am configuring SSRS for remote data source hosted on Azure SQL Server. However, whenever i reach the report viewer, i am presented for a login screen for me to enter the SQL Server login before i can view the report. How can i avoid this and make the report directly shown?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql authentication, should select `Credentials stored securely in the report server` setting at `Data Source` -> `Properties`

[image]